# Changing Chrome Preferences Through Script

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to alter your preferences [Preferences](http://chrome://settings/search#privacy) on your chrome browser through a script? Is this done with selenium? Can anyone help me by writing a python script to change one radio button on the chrome preferences page? Thanks

Comment: Questions **asking us to write code** for your requirements are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they are not about solving a specific problem with code, but rather are asking the community to do your work for you. Instead, make an attempt at writing code and if you encounter a problem, narrow the question to that specific problem and show what has been done so far to try solve it.

Answer (score 6):

it is possible to alter the preferences, not sure if this has been answered for you already but it is done on a user by user basis so if you have more than one user you will need to alter the preferences for each of the accounts, but the preferences file is found in:
Windows: `"%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\"`
Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`
Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/`
it depends on how many accounts have chrome setup but if its just the one the default account is as you guessed it "Default" so it will be in the folder Default inside that folder.

In the Default folder there is a file called Preferences this particular file is a JSON file and it is setup with the preferences for both extensions and for the chrome user *(just to note the file extension is blank but its is formatted in JSON)*, if you wish to adjust it i recommend take a copy of the file and then open Chrome change the setting you wanted to change then close Chrome and compare the two so you know exactly which setting to change, then its just a matter of a string regular expression replacement to modify it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the list of chrome options and capabilities you can pass to the chromedriver in order to modify some preferences.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Hope it helps!